# Camel best practice - where should I call an external web service? Within a Bean, Processor or directly from Route?

Tags: java, apache-camel

In my project, I need to call to multiple external web services, then depend on the response of a web service I can make some change to the header / body of the exchange and then the route will decide which need to do next (direct to another route for example). Assume that I have wrap the calls to external web services in different "service" POJO classes, for example the ProductService to get list of products or to update an existing product etc.So where should I put the code trigger the web service?

1. put productService.getProducts() directly in the route's process
2. create a class inherit from Processor,and inside the process() method I will call productService.getProducts()
3. create a bean which holds a reference to ProductService instance and wrapping the trigger service methods from here

Basically I want to go with option (2) or (3), the reason is because I don't want the route to be messed up with the details of calling external web services. So I just wonder is it considered an "anti-pattern" in term of EIP?

Comment: I would generally recommend defining all your logic into the route definition itself (option 1), going to a custom Processor only if you have a heavyweight business logic processing to do, that would be cumbersome to represent into the route definition.

Comment: So what is the purpose of Processor or Bean? What should be put onto a Bean / Processor exactly?

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of Camel is to handle calls to external systems/services. Put the that logic in your route. Put the business logic and transformations in your processors or beans. It makes it easier to unit test your routes as well.

Comment: So, what if the productService is just to get the list of products from a database? And based on the list of products returned from the service I'll need to update some header, handle some business logic. In that case, would that be OK to wrap all the relevant code inside a method of a Bean  and just trigger the bean's method from the Route?

Comment: Why can't you use Camel to get the list of products from the database, then send that list to your processor to do your update and logic? If in the future you need to get that list from else where you do the change in Camel and avoid changing your business logic.

Comment: Considering Single Responsibility Principle I don't think this is good way to go. Because the Route will end up being messed up with the code to get products from the database. Route should be focused on defining the message producing/consuming. All the other code to handle business logic, database access should be delegating to the relevant Bean or Processor.

Comment: Well that is single responsiblity principle. Camel is responsible only for fetching data. It does not do anything with the data. It hands the data to a bean or processor. That's the contract between the route and the bean. The bean does its magic and returns the data to the route. The route delivers the data. How is this not single responsibility?

Comment: Camel is for message routing, not for data fetching. If it need to fetch data, it should delegate to another service.

Comment: I hope you know that Camel has various components to various databases. So it can indeed be used for data fetching. It has also CSV component to parse CSV files. I think you will run into issues when you write your tests but yeah. The beauty of letting Camel do the connectivity is that in a test scenario you can mock that way and inject some dummy just to test your business logic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375082/read-from-database-and-write-to-file-using-camel